# failure with Ant Android: getType tag

Tags: android, ant, build.xml

I'm building my Android project using ant (on Hudson).  I'm running into an error on the Android build.xml file line 388:

```
<echo level="info">Project Name: ${ant.project.name}</echo>
<gettype projectTypeOut="project.type" />
```

This was running before, but some update broke it, and I can't seem to figure out how.  The AndroidManifest was updated and a new package was added (in the wrong place, actually).

I'm going from this correct output:

```
[echo] Project Name: <Application Name>
[gettype] Project Type: Application
```

To this error

```
<filepath>/workspace/android_build_files/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:388: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:239)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:468)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:515)
at com.android.ant.GetTypeTask.execute(GetTypeTask.java:85)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
--------------- linked to ------------------
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:473)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:515)
at com.android.ant.GetTypeTask.execute(GetTypeTask.java:85)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:239)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:468)
... 18 more
```

Comment: Your build.xml should be autogenerated with "android update project -p .".  Are you building with an old build.xml?

Comment: ah, possibly!  I'm running this through hudson, and don't have that as a pre-build step.  I'll see if that does anything.

Comment: I am running off of an old build.xml, but I do this to set the needed directories and run some scripts to get my app production-ready.  Weird thing is, even without the update, this all works as an ant run on my local machine (after changing the necessary directories in the properties files).

Comment: still not working using the android update project command.  I've removed all custom attributes within my build.xml to custom_rules.xml.  I have everything autogenerated, but still failing on hudson, while building fine on my local environment.

Answer (score 1):

An error in your updated `AndroidManifest.xml` is causing it: the `gettype` task needs to read it, and fails due to some obscure chars in an element (the one you last changed, I'd guess).